# Resize stacklayout scrollview nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Hello I am trying to make a stacklayout change its size (heigth) by scrolling up or down is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. use this way.

```
<DockLayout stretchLastChild="false" class="page-background">
  <GridLayout rows="30*, 70*">
    <GridLayout row="0" borderBottomWidth="3" borderColor="#af152d" rows="auto" class="logo-container">
        <GridLayout rows="*" row="0" class="image-container"></GridLayout>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout row="1" rows="*" orientation="vertical">            
        <ScrollView row="0" orientation="vertical">
            <StackLayout verticalAlignment="top">
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>
  </GridLayout>
</DockLayout>
```